# Save JSON changes locally

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a little app that I built that allows me to input my class details and it parses it into JSON. The basic structure is:

```
var $classes = {

className : {
                subject: $subject;
                teacher: $teacher;
                homework: [];

            }

}
```

I have an interface that will create a new object within the $classes object itself, effectively adding another class to my class list. I don't really want to host this program on a server, so the problem I'm having is getting the browser to save the changes made to the action JS file. As it stands, any change I make is wiped on a refresh.

**Is it possible to manipulate a local JS file via a browser?**

**Can I setup a localhost on my machine and somehow us JS to do what I need?**

I suspect I'll need a server-side language to do this, but I want to be 100% sure. If so, do you think Node.JS would serve me well? I'm trying to continue my JS track before jumping into another language if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your needs, but have you looked at the local storage API? It was added in HTML 5 and allows saving key value data locally in the browser. This would allow you to run your app in the browser without a server backend.

See http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html for more info on the local storage api. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that! In short, I want to be able to make and save changes to the actual classes.js file that is stored locally on my machine, directly through Chrome.

Comment: Hmmm... file access is more complex... might be able to something with the file reader API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Not sure of your use case, but generally it's better to keep code constant and pass different data to the the same code. So the code can be immutable while the data changes. Then you can store changing data in local storage.

Comment: I'm a bit new to databases, so forgive my ignorance. How would I go about having a JSON set of classes that can dynamically grow as I add/remove classes through the year, without changing my initial JSON data?

Comment: JSON is a serialization format, so rather than updating JSON directly, you can deserialize the JSON into javascript objects, update / manipulate the javascript objects however you want, and then serialize those objects back to JSON.